# Can we add links to the LQ review queue proforma comments?

Tags: feature-request, review

I just noticed that our Proforma comments for Link-only answers, that gets automagically added in the Low Quality review queue, doesn't have the link describing why we prefer complete instructions instead.

This is the original:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

This is how it could be:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to [include the essential parts of the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.